# Convergence In probablility implies convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm currently working on the following exercise:

> If $X_n$ is sequence of randon maps with values on a metric space $(S,d)$. Show tha convergence in probablity to a randon map $X$ implies $P\circ X_n^{-1}\Rightarrow P\circ X^{-1}$ as $n\to \infty$.

where $P$ is the a Borel probability on $S$.

> **Observation:** Here convergence in probability means that given $\epsilon>0$ one has $P(d(X_n,X)>\epsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

I was trying to prove it without success when the following example came:

**Example:** Consider the probability space $([0,1].\mathscr{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$ onde $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure. Also consider the sequence of randon maps $X_n=n\cdot 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ and $X\equiv 0$. So $X_n\to X$ in probability. But on the other hand if $f=id$ in $[0,1]$
$$
1=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{E}f(X_n)\neq \mathbb{E}f(X)=0
$$
so $P\circ X_n^{-1}\not\Rightarrow P\circ X^{-1}$ as $n\to \infty$.

**Question:** Are my example correct?? If not  why, and how to prove?

Comment: "Observation: Here convergence in probability means that..." Certainly not (and the fact that X disappears from this formulation should worry you, shouldn't it?).

Comment: Yes are you right. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of weak convergence is
$X_n \implies X$ iff for all $f$ continuous and **bounded** you have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dF_n(x) \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dF(x)$$

But, in your case $P \circ X_n^{-1}$ is a distribution in $\mathbb{R}$, so $f=id$ isn't bounded...

**HINT**: Given two random variables $X,Y$ then for all $a$ and $\epsilon$ you have
$$P(Y \le a) \le P(X\le a +\epsilon)+P(d(X,Y) > \epsilon)$$

then use that $X_n \implies X$ iff $F_n(x) \rightarrow F(x)$ for all $x$ where $F$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo,I knew it was something minor that was missing in my view, but could not find.